# не могу получить список информации о всех подписчиках бота в вайбере (API)

Tags: java, api, бот, viber

Всем привет помогите пожалуйста найти ссылку или запрос который поможет мне вытащить список подпищиков моего вайбер бота. В документации не нашел(

Ссылка https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/get_account_info возвращает результат:

```
{
"status": 0,
"status_message": "ok",
"id": "pa:527939xxxxx",
"chat_hostname": "SN-CHAT-27_",
"name": "TestSending",
"uri": "testsending",
"icon": "https://media-directxxxx",
"background": "https://media-directxxxxx",
"category": "Places of Interest",
"subcategory": "Library",
"location": {
    "lat": 50.4564444,
    "lon": 30.5341673
},
"country": "UA",
"webhook": "https://go.chatpult.com/handler/xxxxxx",
"event_types": [
    "subscribed",
    "unsubscribed",
    "webhook",
    "conversation_started",
    "action",
    "delivered",
    "failed",
    "message",
    "seen"
],
"members": [
    {
        "id": "W0qKyWVKIxxxx",
        "name": "Qlub",
        "avatar": "https:xxxx",
        "role": "admin"
    }
],
"subscribers_count": 3,
"chat_flags": []
```

}
И вроде все работает, но как мне получить список информации о всех подписчиках?
Спасибо огромное заранее!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вайбер не предоставляет такого метода - только работа из слушателями на каком-нибудь сервере.